# how to pad my audio sequence in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I have previously fine tuned hubertforsequenceclassification model for emotion classification.I have padded the output of feature extractor using DataCollatorCTCWithPadding.( tutorial i was following: https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-hubert-for-emotion-recognition-in-custom-audio-data-using-huggingface-c2d516b41cd8
)

Now I am using TFHubertModel to finetune the model for another task

```
def create_model():
    input_layer =  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
    embedding_layer = hubert_model.hubert(input_layer)
    print(embedding_layer)
    x = tf.math.reduce_mean(embedding_layer.last_hidden_state, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(124, activation = 'relu', name = "FC_1")(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(90, activation = 'relu', name = "FC_2")(x)
    
    # MultiTask 1: Emotion prediction
    t1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(54, activation = 'relu')(x)
    t1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(t1)
    t1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation =  "relu")(t1)
    op1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = 'softmax', name = "Output1")(t1)
    
    # MultiTask 2: Gender prediction
    t2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(54, activation = 'relu')(x)
    t2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(t2)
    t2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation =  "relu")(t2)
    op2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name = "Output2")(t2)
    
    print(x)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[op1, op2])
    
    return model
```

However I need to pad the input sequence how to do that. I tried using
**tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences** but it was using more than 30GB ram just for 5 samples from training set. Any recommendations on how to pad the sequence.